# C++ program won't print anything with vectors?

Tags: c++

I compiled my program and run it but nothing happened when I tried to narrow the problem down, it turned out anytime I defined a vector nothing would be sent in the output.
In this program, nothing is printed, even the `std:cout` at the start, and I don't understand how to fix this problem. A simple "hello world" works though. Also, I'm on Windows 10 and use VSCode.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>


    int main( void )
    {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
        std::vector<int> g1; 
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
            g1.push_back(i); 
    
        std::cout << "Output of begin and end: "; 
        for (auto i = g1.begin(); i != g1.end(); ++i) 
            std::cout << *i << " "; 
    
        std::cout << "\nOutput of cbegin and cend: "; 
        for (auto i = g1.cbegin(); i != g1.cend(); ++i) 
            std::cout << *i << " "; 
    
        std::cout << "\nOutput of rbegin and rend: "; 
        for (auto ir = g1.rbegin(); ir != g1.rend(); ++ir) 
            std::cout << *ir << " "; 
    
        std::cout << "\nOutput of crbegin and crend : "; 
        for (auto ir = g1.crbegin(); ir != g1.crend(); ++ir) 
            std::cout << *ir << " "; 
    
        return 0; 
    }
```

In terminal (Windows Powershell) I write this command

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
.\test
```

Thank you for answering

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://godbolt.org/z/z3nxrd).

Comment: does the shell close when the program ends?

Comment: the shell doesn't close it just starts waiting for a new command

Comment: In Windows the compliation result will be saved to `test.exe`. Are there some other executables like `test.bat`, `test.com` in the working directory?

Comment: no just the one

Comment: end your `std::cout` statements with `<< std::endl;`

Comment: There's no change

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: What's your compiler version? use command "g++ --version' in cmd line

Comment: You are getting no output at all?

Comment: no output whtasoever and g++ version 9.2.0

Comment: do you have any warning during compilation? Did you already compiled and run a simple "hello world" with this compiler? Try to comment everything after your first cout and compile/run...

Comment: I believe It is not a programming issue, but it is a path/enviroment problem. Does `more test.cpp` produce what you expect? Does `ls` produce what you expect?

Comment: i have compiled and run a simple hello world

Comment: ls and more commands work

Comment: Did you try to execute your program typing "test" from the related directory but using 'cmd prompt' in place of powel shell?

Comment: i get an __gxx_peronality_v0 is unfindable in library dynamic links

Comment: Didn't work same error

Comment: I tested your code with your compiler on [Techie Delight](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/) and it works fine

Comment: In my experience Powershell will **silently suppress errors** arising from missing libraries. You think `g++ test.cpp -o test` succeeds? You better double check that. Because from what I see, it can fail because of missing DLLs and Powershell will happily show you no error message whatsoever. Do you really want to use Powershell as your shell? I don't.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012332/how-to-make-powershell-tell-me-about-missing-dlls).

Answer (score 2):

With the same idea as what was advised by Harry. Try to flush systematically after a cout (not doing it may not guaranty the print when you expect it). using  `<< std::endl` will end the line and flush the ostream (recomanded after each cout). And if you don't want to end the line use simply `<< std::flush`

Comment: @LuckyloneOfficial try running it from command prompt instead of powershell.

Comment: All files are flushed on program exit anyway.

Comment: its not recommended after every single cout, because usually you do not need to flush the stream after each single cout

Answer (score 0):

Found answer: turns out you need to put a dll file `libstdc++-6.dll` into the .exe dir and solved my problem

Comment: That's not a solution, that's a workaround. Take a look at this answer for proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405064/6871623

Comment: @Everyone Static linking is not **the** proper solution. It is **a** solution. It may or may not work for you depending on what exactly you need.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. What's the proper solution?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you are correct, not even my method is a proper solution. A proper solution should let the program dynamically link to the standard library and be able to find it. Unfortunately, the author gave us no information as which compiler he's using. This can all be fixed by adding necessary info to environment variables. Without knowing what compiler he's using we can't help much.

Comment: @Everyone: "I write this command `g++ test.cpp -o test`" looks like information about the compiler to me.  Perhaps not *complete* information, but quite a lot of it.

Comment: Library files need to be either in the same directory as the .exe, as you did, or, better, in a directory that is referenced in the `PATH` environment variable (for linux, it would be the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable). Do you need help editing those? (I wonder why the installer for your compiler did not do that, though.)

Comment: @BenVoigt that's not any information about the compiler. Different implementations can use the same `g++` name. On Windows, this can be MinGW or Cygwin...

Comment: @everyone: But we know that it isn't cl.exe (Microsoft), or clang, or icc (Intel).  Or some obscure compiler, of which there are plenty.  Knowing it is GCC (the compiler collection, not the C compiler) is a substantial amount of information.  To add to your mingw and cygwin possibilities, it could also be Linux GCC running in a WSL distro.